# What is the purpose of "playing shop" with the little girl on the island in Animal Crossing New Leaf?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

When you visit the island in *Animal Crossing New Leaf* there is a little turtle girl sitting on a rug by the door who asks you to bring her fruits, plants etc. so you can play "shop". When you bring her anything, she will buy them from you for a very small number of bells.

Is there any reward or benefit for playing along with her?

Comment: it's much more profitable to sell them on the mainland

Comment: @ratchetfreak I know it's more profitable to do so but I was wondering if there was any point to selling items to the girl.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Searched around a bit, but Leila has no other purpose than to buy your stuff for 5 % of what Reese (Re-Tail) would pay.

Many people compare her to a waste basket, for stuff they don't want to take with them.